# Fetch MySQL table data through PHP along with column header

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get the columns header as first row through PHP? I know the columns name through 'Describe [tablename]' query. But not sure how to fetch them as header in below code.
Any help would be appreciated.
I am using below code to fetch data:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM [tablename]';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">';
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Have a look at [mysqli_fetch_field](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) and its `name` property.

Comment: Can you please point some working example for that. I looked below examples on that page. However, they contains columns name defined in query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print table headers from your database columns, use this code:

```
echo "<tr>";
while ($col = $result->fetch_field()) {
    echo "<th>" . $col->name . "</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) on any row if fetching using associative array. But this way you won't get any column names if your results count is 0.

Example:

```
$columns = array_keys($result->fetch_assoc()[0]);

foreach ($columns as $column) {
    echo $column . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.